# TypeScript - Cannot assign a string to a string-valued property of a generic object

Tags: typescript, generics, static-analysis, typescript2.0, typescript-generics

In TypeScript 3.5.2, I wrote a mapped type `AssignableKeys<T>` that produces a union of all the string-valued keys of type `T` (i.e. all the keys for which `T[K]` is a string).

This mapped type correctly prevents a non-string-valued property from being assigned to a variable typed as `AssignableKeys<T>`.

```js
// Return a union of all keys in `T` that correspond to 
// properties that can be assigned a value of type `TValue`
export type AssignableKeys<T, TValue> = {
  [Key in keyof T]: TValue extends T[Key] ? Key : never
}[keyof T];

interface IObj {
    A: string,
    B: number,
}

// myKey must be a string-valued property of obj.
let myKey: AssignableKeys<IObj, string>;

// This works fine. "A" is a string-valued key of obj.
myKey = "A";

// This is an error (as expected). "B" is NOT a string-valued key of IObj.
myKey = "B";
```

However, assigning a string to a property that corresponds to one of these string-valued-keys fails with an error:

```js
function setProp<T>(obj: T, key: AssignableKeys<T, string>) {
  obj[key] = "banana"; // typescript error (quoted below)
}
```

> Type '"banana"' is not assignable to type 'T[{ [Key in keyof T]:
>   T[Key] extends string ? Key : never; }[keyof T]]'. ts(2322)

In my understanding, any string *should* be assignable to `obj[key]` because `string extends obj[key]` is true.

I'm just wondering if this is some error with my syntax or understanding of the type system, or if it is a limitation of the static type analysis of TypeScript (or a limitation of static type analysis in general).

Of course, I can force the code to work by using `as any`:

```js
function setProp<T>(obj: T, key: AssignableKeys<T, string>) {
  obj[key] = "banana" as any; // no error
}

const myObj: IObj = { A: "", B: 5 };
setProp(myObj, "A"); // great
setProp(myObj, "B"); // error (as expected)
```

But I'd like to know why typescript doesn't like the code in its original form.

Thanks!

Comment: There is a long possible answer about non distributive conditional return types and functional parameters but the more simple answer is that you can't avoid casting if you use a conditional type in a function parameter or return type an example of that can be seen here...
`const take = <T extends string>(something: T): typeof something extends any ? string : string => something;`

Comment: What do you think about `function setProp<K extends keyof any>(obj: Record<K, string>, key: K) {...}` instead?  The compiler will probably be happy with that.  Does that work for your use case?  (the IntelliSense is a bit different for that signature)

Comment: This approach works well. @jcalz Is there a reason, why you declare it `<K extends keyof any>` instead of `<K extends string>` / `<K extends string | number | symbol> ?

Comment: Personal preference I guess? If you only want to support `string` then you could change it.  Otherwise `keyof any` is terser than `string | number | symbol` and is backward compatible to before [this change](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#support-number-and-symbol-named-properties-with-keyof-and-mapped-types)  if that matters.

Comment: @ShanonJackson - If you could post a slightly more detailed explanation about non-distributive conditional return types and functional parameters, I think that would be the answer to my question.

Comment: @jcalz - Thank you for your comments -- they do show a way to make the specific example work. It was really clever of you to invert the constraint -- i.e. my example required any object and a key constrained to that object. Your suggestion allows any key but requires an object constrained to have the given key. That was creative.

Comment: @jcalz ...But the question is not really about making this specific example work, but it's asking why doesn't the original form work? It seems to me that the original code should ensure that a string safely can be assigned to `obj[key]`. But apparently typescript doesn't conclude that it is safe. What is the flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: Your reasoning is fine, but the compiler doesn't perform much analysis on conditional types involving unresolved generic type parameters (the `T` inside the implementation of `setProp` is unresolved).  It's a [design limitation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30728).

Comment: @jcalz - Can you post your last comment as an answer, and I will accept it.